# generate a pyramid of string and transfer it to a string array

Tags: c++, string

Iam writing a program to ask the user number of rows of pyramid required, based on the input the pyramid generated below should be transferred to a string array ie. string s[1] should have first row of the pyramid below, s[2] should have 2nd row of pyramid and so on.

```
        *
      * * *
    * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
```

My Code below shows this output, pls. suggest where Iam going wrong.

```
Enter number of rows: 4
0      *1    *1    **1    ***2  *2  **2  ***2  ****2  *****3*3**3***3****3*****3******3*******
```

```
int main()
{
    int space,rows,m;
    cout <<"Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    std::string s[rows];
    for(int i = 1, k = 0,m=0; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0,m++)
    {
        for(space = 1; space <= rows-i; ++space)
        {
            s[m] += "  ";           
        }
        while(k != 2*i-1)
        {
            s[m] += "*";
            cout<< m<<s[m];
            k++;
       }
        s[m] +='\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `std::string s[rows];` is a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and it's not a standard C++ feature. Use `std::vector<std::string> s(rows);` instead.

Comment: Time to use a debugger.  A Debugger will help you single step through your code, so you can *watch* or *view* variables and their values.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: @OP FYI, there is only one loop you can use for this assignment, and that is the one that goes from row to row.  Writing 3 loops?  Not necessary if you think about it a little deeper.  Note that `std::string` has another constructor that takes a count and a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all your code needs are some minor changes.

**First issue, your output you have produced**:

The issue with your output is simple -- don't output anything in that loop.  When the loop is finished, *then* see what the array of strings has produced.  By printing intermediate output in the loop, you're distorting what is actually being produced.

**Second issue:  Use `std::vector<std::string>`**.

As others mentioned, a dynamic array in C++ is declared by using `std::vector<std::string>`.

Declaring arrays using a runtime value to denote the size, i.e. `string s[rows];` is not C++, but an extension offered to you by the compiler you're using.

Advice is to **not** use this syntax -- it isn't standard, it is not recognized by other compilers (such as Visual C++), if `rows` is large enough, you could exhaust the stack memory, etc.

---

If we address these two issues, here is what is produced:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int space, rows = 4;
    std::vector<std::string> s(rows);
    for (int i = 1, k = 0, m = 0; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0, m++)
    {
        for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space)
        {
            s[m] += "  ";
        }
        while (k != 2 * i - 1)
        {
            s[m] += "*";
            k++;
        }
    }

    // Output the results
    for (auto& v : s)
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
      *
    ***
  *****
*******
```

So you see, once the unnecessary output is removed from within the `while` loop and moved outside of the processing, you're close to the output you want.

---

So what is wrong?  The issue is simple -- just add a space to the `"*"` in the `while` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int space, rows = 4;
    std::vector<std::string> s(rows);
    for (int i = 1, k = 0, m = 0; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0, m++)
    {
        for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space)
        {
            s[m] += "  ";
        }
        while (k != 2 * i - 1)
        {
            s[m] += "* "; // <-- This simple change is all that is done
            k++;
        }
    }

    for (auto& v : s)
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
      * 
    * * * 
  * * * * * 
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, for the detailed explanation and solution